# ¿como puedo listar los oid disponibles en pysnmp?

Tags: python

como de pysmnp no entiendo nada. como hago para discernir entre multiples OID. en el oid que esta en el fondo, si le quito el 2 aparecen cientos de oid disponibles, pero como puedo agarrar el switch y recolectar todos los oid que me ofrece y que me diga cual es cada uno, o que significa cada uno, asi se cual tomar. esto despues va a ir con una interfaz grafica que aun esta en mi cabeza pero que todavia no empece a diseñar

```
def walk(host, oid):
    
    for (errorIndication,
         errorStatus,
         errorIndex,
         varBinds) in nextCmd(SnmpEngine(),
                              CommunityData('XXXXX'),
                              UdpTransportTarget((host, 161)),
                              ContextData(),
                              ObjectType(ObjectIdentity(oid)),
                              lookupMib=False,
                              lexicographicMode=False):

        if errorIndication:
            print(errorIndication, file=sys.stderr)
            break

        elif errorStatus:
            print('%s at %s' % (errorStatus.prettyPrint(),
                                errorIndex and varBinds[int(errorIndex) - 1][0] or '?'), file=sys.stderr)
            break

        else:
            for varBind in varBinds:
                 print('%s = %s' % varBind)

walk('172.18.0.6', '1.3.6.1.2.1.1.9.1.2')
```